# Accessing Data after Splitting into Lists

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I think this is a very beginner question, but searching the web (and SO) hasn't led me to figure out the answer despite trying quite a few solutions. Here's the problem:

I have a csv dataset with many columns, for example: yearID X Y Z. I read this in using: `data<-read.csv("/foo/bar.csv")`
From there, I use X Y and Z to calculate A for each line: `data$A<-(X+Y)/Z`

Now I want to plot the average A in each year, so I do: `list_df <- split(data, data$yearID)`. Hooray, I can see that if I do summary(list_df[[5]]) I see a summary of X Y Z and A for the fifth year.

Here is where I'm stuck, I then try to do something like:

```
for(year in list_df){
xy<-data.frame(mean(year$yearID, na.rm=T), mean(year$A, na.rm=T))
}
```

This loop "works" (it doesn't throw an error), but what comes out in xy is just the last year and the average A for that year. Ideally, I want to eventually plot "Avg A vs YearID." I've tried a number of permutations on the for loop based on other code examples I've found, but none have yet given me a working solution. Suggestions are most welcome to any part of this process, as I've just started learning R.

Cheers,
Zach

Comment: You can do this directly by using `aggregate`; here's an example:  `plot(aggregate(hp~cyl,mtcars,mean),col="blue",pch=19,cex=2.5)`

Comment: If you could include a reproducible example of your dataset in your post, it will likely get you more and better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need the list split out for other reasons, you can use `aggregate`:

```
data <- data.frame(yearId=rep(2010:2014,each=2),X=runif(10,1,100),Y=runif(10,50,150),Z=runif(10,100,200))
data$A <- (data$X+data$Y)/data$Z

data2 <- aggregate(A~yearId,data,mean)
plot(data2$yearId,data2$A)
```

Comment: Hi @ddunn801. Many thanks, aggregate should do what I want. As a secondary question, could you explain what the first line is doing? I don't understand the rep or runif additions to the data.frame method. I could copy paste that command and see if it works, but I'd like to understand the methodology as well.

Comment: You don't need that for your own project. Since you did not provide us with a sample dataset, I just built a quick one on the fly with the same layout that you described. All it does is fill up the cells with random numbers. You can ignore it.